# My BTC is taking way too long to transfer

Tags: mining-pools, unconfirmed-transactions

I earned 0.4 BTC from constant mining. (I use 50BTC). So I clicked payout, and sent them all to my BlockChain account. It's been "In Process" for about 1 day. What's the problem here? Does it usually take this long? Is it because they got hacked recently?

How can I get these BTC to transfer? By the way, the BTC was removed from the 50BTC account, but it's not yet in the BlockChain. Is it suppose to do this?

Thanks.

Sorry for being a noob, it's my first time with BTC.

Comment: You can check the address to which you sent it on blockchain.info or blockexplorer.com and see if the transaction has been seen. Otherwise, you should contact 50BTC directly.

Comment: I just checked. The transaction has not been seen. I checked the address, and it is correct. I don't know what else to do. Does it usually take this long?

Answer (score 0):

Is the transaction showing on blockchain.info as unconfirmed, or not there at all?

If it's unconfirmed, just wait as it may be that the transaction included no or a minimal transaction fee which means it will take a while to be included in a block.

Comment: It's not there at all. It got removed from my 50BTC account, but it hasn't shown anything in Blockchain. It still says "In Process"

Comment: Is my BTC lost? :(

Comment: @JohnWilson: If it doesn't appear on blockchain, then 50BTC never sent it to that address.  So you will have to ask them why it wasn't sent.  There have been some reports of problems with payments from 50BTC, see also the question I linked in my comment above.

Comment: I saw that thread, but I earned that BTC. I didn't get any extra BTC in my account.